# Same Target Namespace for multiple WSDLs

Tags: soap, wsdl, designer, tibco

We got the wsdls from client with the same Target namespace but whenever we created the soap requests using them , getting reference issues and failing.

Tried changing the name space but the same issue in tibco admin. Its working fine in designer .

Can someone suggest to avoid them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide more info on what the actual error is?

TIBCO BusinessWorks sometimes is picky about the same definition on the same namespace in different fragments, so that can be it.

Different definitions (complexTypes, simpleTypes and elements) in the same namespace and in different fragments seem to work okay.